# How to get data selected by id using axios in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

> app.js:50345 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop
>   "data". Expected Object, got String with value "".

this how I route the data and pagination

```
Route::get('project',function(){
    return App\project::latest()->paginate(5);});
```

this how I display

```
<td>{{projectownerdata && projectownerdata.project_id}}</td>
```

this is my script in vue

```
<script>
    export default {

            data(){
              return{
              projectownerdata :{
              },
               form: new Form({
              project_id:'',
              project_name:'',
              project_code:'',
              tct_number:'',
              project_status:'New',
              address:''

                    })            

                }
            },

            methods:{
      //For Pagination
               getResults(page = 1) {
                     axios.get('api/project?page=' + page)
                      .then(response => {
                        this.projectownerdata = response.data
                })
              },

loadProjects(){
   axios.get('api/project/'+ this.$route.params.id)
        .then(response => {
            this.projectownerdata = response.data
        });

}                        
            },

            created(){
            this.loadProjects();


            },

            }





</script>
```

Comment: Instead of using + change it to ,

Comment: debug `console.log(response);` in `axios`, see what happen with the response.

Comment: I tried but its not working :(

Comment: I Solved it. I forgot to call the ID on my controller -_-